# GDAL Raster: How to obtain the cell ( and also the position) where maximum occurs?

Tags: raster, gdal, gdal.net

I can obtain the maximum/minimum value of a raster via the [ComputeRasterMinMax](https://www.gdal.org/classGDALRasterBand.html#ac7761bab7cf3b8445ed963e4aa85e715) code:

```
  using (var ds = Gdal.Open(tiffFile, Access.GA_ReadOnly))
  {
    var nCol = ds.RasterXSize;
    var nRow = ds.RasterYSize;
    var allValues = new int[nCol * nRow];
    Band band = ds.GetRasterBand(1);
    band.ReadRaster(0, 0, nCol, nRow, allValues, nCol, nRow, 0, 0);   
    double[] minMax = new double[2];
    band.ComputeRasterMinMax(minMax, 0);

  }
```

As per documentation, `minMax[0]` is the minimum value, and `minMax[1]` is the maximum value of the band.

But how to get *the cell* that these maximum and minimum occurs, besides actually looping through the array and compare the item one by one?

Comment: try R, `library(raster); r <- raster("your.tif"); which.max(r)` - you can get cell properties with functions like `xyFromCell()` . (There are smarter ways to lazily get the outline of a pixel in R, but this would work to add the res(r)/2 to that xy point. )

Answer (score 1):

You can return the max pixel of a raster simply using `gdal_calc` as follows:

```
gdal_calc.py -A  input_raster.tif --calc="(A==max(A.flatten()))*1" --outfile=max_pixel.tif --overwrite
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the value of the "max" cell, reclassify everything that isn't that value to NA, convert the raster to polygon, then find the centroid of the polygon. It's the gorilla approach.

Comment: Can you show some code snippet how this can be done ?